# Function gets four arguments instead of three - why doesn't this break?

Tags: haskell

Reading "Real World Haskell", on page 95 the author provides an example:

```
myFoldl f z xs = foldr step id xs z
    where step x g a = g (f a x)
```

My question is: Why does this code compile? `foldr` takes only three arguments - but here, it is passed four: `step`, `id`, `xs`, `z`.

For example, this doesn't work (because sum expects one):

```
sum filter odd [1,2,3]
```

instead I must write:

```
sum $ filter odd [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the type of `foldr`:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Can we figure out how it becomes a four-argument function?  Let's give it a try!

1. we're giving it `id :: d -> d` as the second parameter (`b`), so let's substitute that into the type:

   ```
   (a -> (d -> d) -> (d -> d)) -> (d -> d) -> [a] -> (d -> d)
   ```
2. in Haskell, `a -> a -> a` is the same as `a -> (a -> a)`, which gives us (removing the last set of parentheses):

   ```
   (a -> (d -> d) -> (d -> d)) -> (d -> d) -> [a] -> d -> d
   ```
3. let's simplify, by substituting `e` for `(a -> (d -> d) -> (d -> d))` and `f` for `(d -> d`), to make it easier to read:

   ```
   e -> f -> [a] -> d -> d
   ```

So we can plainly see that we've constructed a four-argument function!  My head hurts.

---

Here's a simpler example of creating an n + 1-argument function from an n-arg func:

```
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

`id` is a function of one argument.

```
Prelude> id id id id id 5
5
```

But I just gave it 5 args!

Comment: I don't understand why you can do `id id 5`, but you can't do: `foo x=x+1; bar y=y+1; foo bar 1`?

Comment: @drozzy -- it's all about types and polymorphism.  Take `id :: a -> a`: you can substitute *any* type for `a`.  However, `foo` is different, because it has constraints:  it needs a number:  `foo :: (Num a) => a -> a`.  `bar :: (Num a) => a -> a` is not an instance of the `Num` typeclass and thus does not satisfy the `(Num a)` constraint of `foo`.

Comment: @drozzy Perhaps it will help if we clarify the associativity of function application! Remember that `id id 5` parses as `(id id) 5` -- that is, give `id` as an argument to `id` first, and then `5` as an argument to the result -- not as `id (id 5)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yap, I knew that :-)

Answer (score 10):

It's because of how polymorphic `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Here, we've instantiated `b` to a function type, let's call it `c -> c`, so the type of `foldr` specializes to (for example)

```
foldr :: (a -> (c -> c) -> (c -> c)) -> (c -> c) -> [a] -> c -> c
```

Comment: You could also point out that the neutral element in the original question is already a function, `id`.

Answer (score 9):

> `foldr` only takes 3 arguments

Wrong. All functions in Haskell take exactly 1 argument, and produce exactly 1 result.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

See, `foldr` takes one argument `(a -> b -> b)`, and produces 1 result: `b -> [a] -> b`. When you see this:

```
foldr step id xs z
```

Remember, it is just shorthand for this:

```
((((foldr step) id) xs) z)
```

This explains why this is nonsense:

```
sum filter odd [1,2,3]
(((sum filter) odd) [1,2,3])
```

`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a` takes a list as its input, but you gave it a function.